# Creating Multiculture product using Kentico API 9

Tags: c#, kentico

I am developing a tool for migrating data from Sitecore to Kentico. I'm looking for a way to create a product with two different cultures using Kentico API 9. I want to extract data from Sitecore and store it to Kentico using API.

I've checked out the Kentico documentation and it provides us with code to create a product:

```
// Gets a department
DepartmentInfo department = DepartmentInfoProvider.GetDepartmentInfo("NewDepartment", SiteContext.CurrentSiteName);

// Creates a new product object
SKUInfo newProduct = new SKUInfo();

// Sets the product properties
newProduct.SKUName = "NewProduct";
newProduct.SKUPrice = 120;
newProduct.SKUEnabled = true;
if (department != null)
{
   newProduct.SKUDepartmentID = department.DepartmentID;
}
newProduct.SKUSiteID = SiteContext.CurrentSiteID;

// Saves the product to the database
// Note: Only creates the SKU object. You also need to create a connected Product page to add the product to the site.
SKUInfoProvider.SetSKUInfo(newProduct);
```

But I can't figure out how to create a multi-culture product with attachments per culture.

Would any one help or recommend a different way to migrate data from Sitecore to Kentico?

Answer (score 3):

You should use **DocumentHelper.InsertDocument()** located in **CMS.DocumentEngine** to save the page in the first culture, and then use **DocumentHelper.InsertNewCultureVersion()** to add other cultures to the page. Your code is capable of creating SKUs, so to create product pages for those SKUs, you should add the following:

```
TreeProvider tree = new TreeProvider(MembershipContext.AuthenticatedUser);

//Get a parent node, under which the product pages will be created.
//Replace "/Store/Products" with page alias of the parent page to use.
TreeNode parentNode = tree.SelectSingleNode(SiteContext.CurrentSiteName, "/Store/Products", "en-us");

//Create a new product page
TreeNode node = TreeNode.New("CMS.Product", tree);

//Set the product page's culture and culture specific properties, according to your needs
node.DocumentCulture = "en-us";
node.DocumentName = "ProductPage - English";
node.NodeSKUID = newProduct.SKUID;

//Save the page
DocumentHelper.InsertDocument(node, parentNode, tree);

//Set the product pages culture and culture specific properties for another culture
node.DocumentCulture = "es-es";
node.DocumentName = "ProductPage - Spanish";
node.NodeSKUID = newProduct.SKUID;

//Save the new culture version
DocumentHelper.InsertNewCultureVersion(node, tree, "es-es");
```

To add an **attachment** to a document, use **DocumentHelper.AddAttachment()** before saving the document to the database.
Then just repeat the block after **DocumentHelper.InsertDocument** for any number of cultures you need to add.

Hope this helps.